# jQuery - How to check if child exists with id = a URL?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I (am pretty sure I) have to use jQuery for a portion of a page I'm trying to create and this is basically my first day doing jQuery.

For the following if/else, I'm first trying to check if a `<div>` with an id equaling the variable `url` exists. If it exists, it will write text into the div. If the element does not exist, the `else` will create a new div with an `id` attribute, and text containing the same response, and append it to an `<a href>` tag associated with it.

```
Function() {
    ...
    ...
    ...
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        if ($("div#"+url+"").length) {
            document.getElementById(url).innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
        else {
            $("a[href='" + link + "']").append(
                $("<div></div>", {
                    "id": url,
                    "text": xhr.responseText
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

If I made that sound confusing, here's a visual representation of what I want to have happen in the HTML DOM.

Before

```
<a href="http://foo.com" onclick="Function('url')">Foo</a>
```

After link is clicked.

```
<a href="http://foo.com" onclick="Function('url')">Foo</a><div id="http://foo.com">xhr.responseText</div>
```

The error I get in the console is
**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.foo.com**
Because it says it is a syntax error, I know I must be using .length wrong, but the selector for `id` is `#` so I don't understand where the error is. I've done a bunch of scouting across SO and http://api.jquery.com/length/ for jquery syntax for checking if a child exists and I've tried using some logical operators but it's always the same error at the if statement. I also tried using encodeURIComponent(url) in case it didn't like some characters in the URL but that didn't fix it either.

Comment: You can't use a URL as an HTML id because it contains invalid characters

Comment: and I guess encoding the URL doesn't matter?

Comment: You can go about it the opposite way. The `$().closest()` method will try to match a selector against a node's ancestors. So you can check that the id of the child exists, and that one of its ancestors matches the parent you want.

Comment: No encoding doesn't solve the problem because the percent sign is still invalid. Also you probably don't want periods in your ids because they could confuse jQuery.

Comment: What you should do is use `data-`-attributes. using a `data-url="..."` attribute would let you use `$("div[data-url]")` to find them. This is the cleanest way if you insist on having the URL as an attribute.

Comment: @dave Ok thanks Dave. I guess I was on the right path thinking the URL was issue when I tried using encodeURIComponent since it works for my xhr.open("get","url").  Thanks for confirming :)

Comment: @IngwiePhoenix wow that's great to know! I wish you would've put that as an answer so I could give a check mark :o I could alter the question title as well to indicate my id is a URL as to make your answer especially valid.

Also, the way I'm doing this, the url seems like it has to be. Since I'm still pretty new, there are probably other ways around this, but to get this working right now, using the url is the way I am going if it can work (and as you have pointed out, it can).

Answer (score 2):

you're question confuses me, but if you're looking to see if an id exists on the page try this

`if($('#youId').length){//the object exists}`

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I'm trying to check for.

Comment: if I'm reading that correctly, you're just saying take out the "div" that I had in as div#youId. I've done that and it didn't work either.

Comment: if you're id belongs to a div than `div#yourId` is equally valid

Comment: whats more likely is that your id contains illegal characters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: yeah dave up top confirmed that for me :) Thanks for the suggestions though.